# Possible to get previous value of object in Parse Cloud Code AfterSave?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have an `AfterSave` function that updates something else based on the previous value of the object that was just saved. Simply knowing that the object has changed with `object.existed()` is not enough.

Is there any way to get the previous value of an object's property without implementing a costly workaround and increasing the number of API calls?

Is it even possible to get the previous value of an object in the `AfterSave` function?

When I call `object.previous("value")`, I get an undefined value.

Comment: can you use beforeSave instead?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm trying to update a counter field on another class based on the change in value of another class. So before I update another class, I think it makes more sense to  wait for the other class to save. I think `beforeSave` is typically used to enforce a particular data format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is helpful or if it would be considered too costly of a workaround, but you could add a column to the object that is being updated that stores the previous value of the original column. This would allow you to access the previous value in the `AfterSave` function.

Comment: Funnily enough, this is exactly what I ended up doing. It's definitely a decent temporary solution, but I hope Parse makes the `object.previous("value")` from Backbone soon.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have reputation to comment on dstefanis' approach.

This approach is good when one endpoint is changing the value - and indeed I've used it before to this end.

There's a critical limitation in that if multiple endpoints are writing, they may still keep over-writing both the "current" and "old" fields.  This means it can't be used to give any strict assurances - e.g. "this field will never be decremented".

A conflict-safe way is to do a parse query by objectId, and pick up the old value.  You can then do your own conflict resolution.  I have this tested and working :-)