# request.object.previous() is not working in beforeSave()

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to check the current and previous value of an attribute in the beforeSave(). So i tried to use request.object.previous("attribute_name") but it is still returning the current changed value. Although the .ditry() is returning TRUE which means that the value is changed. Any idea what is wrong here ? I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the .previous() isn't actually part of the Parse.com sdk, but simply inherited from backbone.

> In a beforeSave handler, I have something like:
>
> ```
> if(object.dirty("attr")) { 
>    console.log("After: " + object.get("attr") + ", Before: " + object.previous("attr")); }
> ```
>
> The value returned by 'previous' is always the same. Is this functionality actually
>   implemented? I've seen a few threads elsewhere that imply it's not -
>   if so, can you remove it from the API docs until it's done?
>
> If it doesn't work, is the correct workaround to query the previous
>   object? Or does 'changedAttributes' work?
>   Oh, I now see that 'previous' is some cruft from Backbone.

[source1](https://parse.com/questions/objectpreviousattr-in-beforesave-is-never-the-previous-value)

> previous is a method [inherited from Backbone.Model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-previous). It won't return the previous value of a field in Cloud Code.

[source2](https://parse.com/questions/objectprevious-isnt-working-in-cloud-code-aftersave)

Might not be the answer you're looking for, so as a way to workaround the lack of the .previous implementation this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568564/possible-to-get-previous-value-of-object-in-parse-cloud-code-aftersave) out:

> Don't know if this is helpful or if it would be considered too costly
>   of a workaround, but you could add a column to the object that is
>   being updated that stores the previous value of the original column.
>   This would allow you to access the previous value in the AfterSave
>   function.